# Defining a PHP variable using a field

Tags: entities

Is is possible to define a PHP variable using a field?

eg. In the field a contributor would enter [ABC]

which would translate to: `<?php $VARIABLE = '[ABC]'; ?>`

which would be repeatedly used in the node as:

```
<img src="http://www.example.com/<?php echo "$VARIABLE"; ?>/image_01.jpg/>
<img src="http://www.example.com/<?php echo "$VARIABLE"; ?>/image_02.jpg/>
```

etc

Comment: Why would you want the user to define the path of the images?

Comment: I would look into the https://drupal.org/project/token_filter or https://drupal.org/project/customfilter modules as I think they solve what you are trying to ask here

Comment: Sorry I meant contributor, not user - edited.

Unfortunately those modules will not work.

I am essentially trying to post a buzz feed image list style article. The images live on an external server in a static location. The variable needs to be set to define the folder location and the file name (among other things). I have tried to simplify the problem to the lowest common denominator in the hope I would get the simplest answer giving me a starting point (at the minute I am completely lost)

Comment: Btw you should rethink the title of this question.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a simple text field to store the string, and then a [custom formatter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.api.php/function/hook_field_formatter_info/7) to render it as an image. Then under "Manage display" for the content type, you choose the formatter you just created.

If you don't want to create the custom formatter programmatically, you could use the [Custom formatters](https://drupal.org/project/custom_formatters) module.

If you want to use the value of the text field for more than one output element, you could create [Display suite custom fields](https://drupal.org/node/1795314) using this value e.g. as a token.

Answer (score 0):

What you're asking for (linking remote images) can be done the [File Field Sources](https://drupal.org/project/filefield_sources) module. This way for instance drupal will "copy down" the remote image locally and you may use Image Styles and other things to theme it (locally). If the remote image is deleted or the URL changes you're website in turn will not break.

> FileField Sources is an extension to the FileField module. The
>   FileField module lets you upload files from your computer through a
>   CCK field. The FileField Sources module expands on this ability by
>   allowing you to select new or existing files through additional means,
>   including:
>
> - Re-use files by an auto-complete textfield
> - Attach server-side files uploaded via FTP
> - Transfer files from a remote server (cURL required)
> - Paste a file directly from the clipboard (Drupal 7 only)
> - Select existing files through the IMCE file browser
>
> Although FileField
>   Sources provides several built-in sources, it can be extended by any
>   module through an API for creating new sources. Users can toggle
>   between any of the available methods for selecting a file.

See these [Additional File Field Sources add-on Modules](https://drupal.org/search/site/filefield%20sources).

Retrieving the remote image to a local version is the "typical" Drupal pattern here. If you want the specific drop-downs for certain remote paths or folders -- try to extend the feature-set by using their API to write your own little dialog similiar to the default ones (see the project page) and have its form values be your desired criteria.

**EDIT:**

it looks like the [AmazonS3](https://drupal.org/project/amazons3) module can work with the FileFieldSources module from this issue https://drupal.org/node/1585188. It stores/retrieves files to your S3 account. I still think you can use the FileFieldSources API to build whatever interface you need to poke, prod and otherwise fetch data from Amazon for your images and feeds. In short I would try to use the AmazonS3 module + FileFieldSources as the groundwork to create you're own custom UI for your contributors.

Comment: Unfortunately our images exist on a remote amazon server because we have been using a massive amount of bandwidth (250gb a day) and having images locally is not an option.

Comment: If I find an answer to my OP I will use the information to create a content type that enables my contributors to create an image based articles similar to this one:

http://www.newageman.co.uk/14-time-travelling-celebrities

Comment: These articles are currently being produced using php code that lives in the body area but as my contributors are not developers I wanted to give them text fields only to work with

Comment: @user3169181 please see my edit. If I were you I'd try to avoid hand crafting all this stuff by hand -- and try to leverage existing module based APIs. Without more details this is the best help I can offer at this time.